# How can i access to mssql database with pymssql on google colab?

Tags: python, sql-server, google-colaboratory, pymssql

I want to use my mssql database from my website in google colab.

I install pymssql on google colab. When i check sql connection with pmssql on colab, i see OperationalError: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist. but when i check that on my windows with the same code i can access to my db. i try to install pyodbc on colab but i cant install that.

! pip install pymssql
import pymssql 
con = pymssql.connect(host='server',user='user',password='pass',database='mydb')

cursor = con.cursor()

I want to access to my database on google colab but i cant.